# Combining MVC4 and Symfony2 users in one database

Tags: c#, php, mysql, symfony, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a webapp that has a frontoffice which uses Symfony2, and a backoffice that uses ASP.NET MVC4 (before you tell me, yes I know this is a ridiculous setup but these are constraints to which we have to adhere).

I would now like to have one user table in my database from which users can log in in both the frontoffice (SF2) and the backoffice (MVC4). I use FOSUserBundle to manage my users on the Symfony2 side, but I haven't decided which membership provider I should be using for the MVC4 part of the app, mostly because I have no idea how to authenticate users on the ASP side.

FOSUserBundle uses SHA512 with 5000 iterations when registering a user/changing a password. Both the hashed password and the password salt are stored in the database -- this all works fine. The issue is that I'm not sure how I should be using this data in the MVC4 application; I did some research to see if I can change the hashing algorithm etc, but this requires me to make a custom membership provider which is a little daunting for someone who's never worked with MVC4 before.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? It'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting problem. I'm pretty sure the Symfony2 authentication stuff will be flexible enough to read from the MVC4 side, if you find that going the other way is too onerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`write a custom membership provider`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers) that will query your database. Basically you have to write a class that derives from [`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) and implement the methods you want to use. There are many methods, but you probably don't need to override them all. For example the `ValidateUser` method takes a username and password and its up to you to handle the situation.

For example:

```
public class MyCustomMembershipProvider: MembershipProvider
{
    ...
}
```

and then you could register this custom membership provider in your web.config to replace the default one:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyCustomMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MyCustomMembershipProvider" 
             type="MvcApplication1.Providers.MyCustomMembershipProvider" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Now when inside your LogOn action you call the `Membership.ValidateUser` it will delegate to your custom provider.

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly give that a try!